# Are charges absolute or relative?

Tags: charge, neutrinos

The charge of a particle is (mostly) an intrinsic property of the particle.

One of the few elementary particles that doesn't have a charge are neutrino's.

Does that mean that it is still possible that scientists ever will found a sort of neutrino particle that has a sort of charge-relation with our neutrino like an elektron it has with a proton? That is a relative charge.

Or is it not possible because a neutrino has absolute not any charge in any way?

Comment: what do you mean by a kind of neutrino ? why would you use this name/category if you find a charged particle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use "relative vs absolute" to mean "distinguishable vs undetermined".

If this is the case, we could say it is a possibility that yes, the charge of neutrino is undetermined (relative). This is because having a charge, is physics jargon for "susceptible of certain kind of interaction".

Thus neutrinos have no electric charge (do not "feel" electric forces) but do have lepton charge (feel weak forces). And the same applies to all elementary particles and all such properties (maybe spin is a little trickier but in a sense, also the same case).

Thus it is plausible that we could detect a new kind of fundamental interaction to which they are susceptible, in which case your assertion would be true.

Comment: So if neutrino's have lepton charge, why are they always be defined as uncharged?

Comment: Well I don't know what you have seen, but in wikipedia you can check how they have lepton charge. I know of no source that says otherwise.

Comment: Of course, I was too much focussed on elektric charge

Comment: @igael without electric charge, even a particle with spin cannot interact with EM field, unless it is a magnetic monopole, which has not been found and for which there is more evidence of its non-existence than the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean exactly by "charge." A neutrino has no electric charge, so we'll never find an electrically charged particle that interacts electrically with it.

On the other hand, neutrinos (and other particles) have other intrinsic properties that really only differ from charge in their function. For example, neutrinos have mass, so they attract other particles with mass. Quarks have color, which like charge dictates how they interact with each other. I've even seen specifically "color charge" used to refer to that property, though I don't know if that is professionally accepted in general. At any rate, the generic term "charge" just refers to the intrinsic property that sources the interaction between two particles, so yes, we can find a particle that interacts with neutrinos in a way that could be called "charge."

Comment: Includes your answer also anti-neutrino's which can be qualified as charge-partner?

Comment: I don't believe so. As far as I know, an antineutrino and a neutrino would have the same interaction as two of either would have. On the other hand, neutrinos conserve lepton number, which can constrain their interactions with other particles in a particular way, which is what I'm using to define "charge-like." A more educated particle phycisict will have to set the record straight for us.